# Is the sign test appropriate to test whether values in one distribution are generally lower than the other?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, bias, sign-test

Generally, the sign test is used to test the hypothesis that the difference median is zero between two continuous distributions ([Sign test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test)).

I am trying to understand whether it can be adapted to prove that the values from one distribution are generally lower than the other. Or are there **better tests** which can be designed for this purpose?

Data available: Suppose that I have the average GMAT scores from 50 universities. There are 2 averages per university, the first one being the average of those candidates who have studied mathematics at a graduate level while the second one is for those who have not.

A simple plot shows that students who have studied math score higher. However, I would like to prove this fact statistically using a test (and a p-value?). Conversely, I may also like to prove in another case that there is no difference.

[image: Plot of average scores by universities separated by Math NoMath]

Comment: Do you have the raw data that went into the averages?

Comment: @PeterFlom Created a temporary version which should follow similar trends - http://pastebin.com/xzcKwRsA

Comment: If you  have the raw data, you can use a regression model.

Comment: @PeterFlom Pardon my ignorance, but even if I build a linear regression model thus getting one as a function of the other, how do I prove that generally one series is "lesser" than the other? Just using the magnitude of the slope?

Comment: What exactly do you want to prove? You can do quantile regression about many quantiles, if you  want.

Comment: What is the population about which you wish to make inferences? (It looks to me like you might even already have the population rather than a sample from it, but it depends on the type of statement you wish to make)

Comment: @PeterFlom I am trying to disprove the assertion: Students who have not studied math score as well or better in GMAT as compared to those who have. I am guessing this statement can be framed as a null hypothesis, and a p-value obtained. Please note that we cannot assume that the two distributions are normal.